# In a hogan-express node.js express application, How can I use different template than global template in particular routes?

Tags: node.js, express, backend, hogan.js, templating-engine

Okay so I'm new to express, templating, and back-ends.  I have been searching all-day to answer this question to no avail.  So, I thought I would ask it here.

**How can you use a different template for particular routes other than the global template declared** in a [hogan-express](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hogan-express), [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [express](http://expressjs.com/) application?  I still would like to use partials so keep that in mind if you are referring me to try a different framework or something. (not sure how common partials are though...)

### The Code

Here is code I have looked over for Hogan-express from the docs themselves (it's been converted from coffescript to regular javascript.)

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

// start example code from docs.  
// I use code like this in my app.js/server.js file

app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.set('layout', 'layout'); // the global template as I explained above.

app.set('partials', {
  foo: 'foo'
});

app.enable('view cache');

app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));

// I have this function referenced from a different file...
// in my code I'll explain below.

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.locals = {
    name: 'Andrew'
  };
  return res.render('template', {
    partials: {
      message: 'message'
    }
  });
});
```

my code differs as follows

```
// in---file---> 'app.js'

var routes = require('./routes/index.js');

app.get('/', routes.index);

// ---in---file---> '/routes/index.js'

exports.index =  function(req,res){

    var template_data = {
        posts : blogposts, 
        currentUser : req.user
    };

    res.render('index.html', template_data);  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add `layout:'layout2'` to your template_data object that is sent as the second parameter into `res.render`.

```
// in---file---> 'app.js'

var routes = require('./routes/index.js');

app.get('/', routes.index);

// ---in---file---> '/routes/index.js'

exports.index =  function(req,res){

    var template_data = {
        layout:'layout2', // this is the important addition.
        posts : blogposts, 
        currentUser : req.user
    };

    res.render('index.html', template_data);  
};
```

The new layout will work for each route you declare it in, but won't overwrite the global template for other routes not declared in this fashion.